On boot after I said yes it shows yyyyyyy on the left side
I have a Lenovo ThinkPad T440p laptop that I bought secondhand. It does not boot. It just shows [initramfs] On boot after I said yes it shows yyyyyyy on the left side of the screen. What do I do now? Please explain what to do about it in simple terms.

You have not given any info that can be used to offer any help. Please read the info on this link and edit the question. https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask  All questions need to have the Ubuntu type server or desktop and the Ubuntu version. Please edit the question and add this. As well in this case the hardware config is also needed. How was Ubuntu installed?

Please [edit] your question and start from the beginning. Tell us what you have done (have you installed Ubuntu perhaps? How? Which one?), tell us what happens (add a screenshot if possible, and also describe it: what exactly does it show?). Add any details that might be relevant. Has this machine ever booted before? What changed since the last time? Do you have a bootloader (e.g. grub)? Which one? How was that installed?

This boot problem occurs when trying to install Ubuntu from a bootable live Ubuntu USB, right?

This glitchy problem has "possible hardware issue" almost stuck on it like a laptop sticker, but the trick is how to confirm it. Try booting your laptop from an Ubuntu Server 24.04 bootable USB. If your Lenovo ThinkPad T440p can't boot to a text interface it most likely has a hardware issue.
